# How to update shared preference instantly after reading data from volley?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to store data retrieved from API using volley, but if I made 2 different requests followed by each other , it shows the first request only before updating .

I have to request the second one again to store the new data.

Is there a solution?

```
SharedPreferences m=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
String resp=m.getString("Response","");
return  resp;
private void share (String x)
{
    SharedPreferences 
     m=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=m.edit();
    editor.putString("Response",x);
    editor.commit();

}
```

Comment: You have to store all your different response with different keys.

Comment: I did as you said but the result remains the same